# In the reals with the usual topology, is every open set is a $G_\delta$ set?

Tags: general-topology

> In the reals with the usual topology, prove or disprove: Every open set is a $G_\delta$ set.

Having real trouble with this, I can prove the other way but I can't seem to get my head around this direction.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: A side note, a Gδ set is the intersection of countably many open sets however I am guessing this is common knowledge.

Comment: You can prove the other way? It is not true that a $G_\delta$ set is open (e.g.: $\{0\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (-1/n,1/n)$).

Comment: Your example above is dealing with an infinite number of sets whereas $G_\delta$ is the intersection of countably many open sets

Comment: "[countable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set)" means "finite or countably infinite". (In fact, some take "countable" to mean "countably infinite".)

Comment: well then i do apologise for the flaws in the terminology used, but I am sure that the question should be worded in terms of a finite number of open sets. sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $A$ is $G_\delta$ if and only if it is a countable intersection of open sets. If $U$ is open, can you find a countable sequence of open sets whose intersection is $U$?

Comment: hint to the hint: a sequence need not have distinct elements...

Comment: Alternative hint to the hint: $1$ is a countable cardinal number.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For any set $X$ and any subset $Y\subseteq X$, what is $Y\cap Y$?

Comment: So do you mean that it follows trivially - as in we can write each open set as simply intersections of themselves?

Comment: @katherinebarry: Yup, that's right!